# Send xml as data param to GET method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, xml

I have this jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/upload?mathml=" + mathml + "&fileName=math", //+ Utility.getRandomInt(1, 100),
    dataType: "json",

    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        console.log("Sending request to generate image...");
    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        img = result;
        tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="MathML (base64):' + window.btoa(mathml) + '" src="' + img + '"/>');
        console.log("Success: " + textStatus);
        editor.windowManager.close();
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error: " + textStatus + ". Error: " + errorThrown + " ");
    }
});
```

And I am sending raw xml/mathml in the url to the GET method. It gives me error that the page was not found since the characters: "<", ">" get converted to url characters with "%" in front.

Is there some jQuery/JavaScript function to do this or should I convert those characters back to "<", ">" on the server side in C#?

Note: I am developing MVC 4/C# web application in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why dont you use POST instead?